2000's movie about aliens invading via plants
I saw this movie on netflix around 2010. I think it was Canadian and looked like it was from the 2000s. It involved a young woman and young man doing some kind of investigation on a plant company, turns out the plants are a way for the aliens to colonize earth. I think there was a scene where like black spores or something comes out of the plants?

Any chance it is "Invasion of the Body Snatchers" (1979)?
Wikipedia:

The plot begins in deep space, where a race of gelatinous creatures
  abandon their dying world. They make their way to Earth and land in
  San Francisco. They fall on plant leaves, assimilating them and
  forming small pods with pink flowers. Elizabeth Driscoll (Brooke
  Adams), an employee at the San Francisco Health Department, is one of
  several people who bring the flowers home.

Color green dominates the cover of the blu-ray:

Alien invasion, plants/flowers are in the movie. At the end of the movie, Donald Sutherland's character infiltrates, and a bit later destroys the alien "plant factory":


You can watch the complete movie here, the alien plant factory part starts ca. at 1:30:00:




no, this was a different movie. in the movie i saw, the aliens had like...greenhouses of plants. also "invasion of the body snatchers" is much older than the movie i saw.

Not optimisitic, but could it have been:
The Day of the Triffids (2009)

OR
The Day of the Triffids (1982)
Netflix


no, i don't believe that it was either one of those. the cover image was mainly bright green (like the color of "tropical plants").

I can see how you got there, though.  IIRC, in the original novel, the triffids were of alien origin.

movie was found with the help of a friend! infected (2008).

Please add details to your answer.
